# TAI for MS Azure with Websphere Application Server setup for Idp initiated flow not working

Tags: azure-active-directory, websphere, single-sign-on, saml, idp

I am trying to setup saml sso configuration for my application which is deployed in websphere.

Idp- Azure AD
SP - Websphere application server when my target application deployed

Done TAI configuration as per the Ibm document . But when I hit the test button from idp I could see the saml response in network tab. but i couldn't login to my application and also didn't get any trace related to saml in log files also however i have enabled logs for saml in Troubleshoot. My doubt is sometimes am getting trace which are related to TAI during server stop. For each request should i be getting TAI trace ? and why my saml response not getting intercepted in TAI. How exactly the interception happen with saml response and how do we get to know that saml response got validated.

[15/4/21 16:18:42:855 IST] 00000096 TrustAssociat A   SECJ0121I: Trust Association Init class com.ibm.ws.security.web.saml.ACSTrustAssociationInterceptor loaded successfully

acs url -> https://localhost:/browserTest  (which is my actual target application url)
metadata and signing certificates also imported correctly.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The acs URL has format like this:

> `https://<hostname>:<sslport>/samlsps/<any URI pattern string>`

if you want to use your application URL

```
 https://localhost:/browserTest
```

as acs URL, this UR must be able to accept HTTP POST.

Comment: Changed my acs Url and done required configuration.  acsUrl=[https://localhost:<port>/samlsps/acs]

Comment: Getting below logs in Trace :00000001 TrustAssociat 3  getTrustAssociationConfig returns[not null]
[20/4/21 18:56:40:925 IST] 00000001 TrustAssociat 3  isTrustAssociationEnabled returns [true][20/4/21 18:56:40:925 IST] 00000001 TrustAssociat 3  getTrustAssociationConfig returns[not null][20/4/21 18:56:40:925 IST] 00000001 TrustAssociat 3  getInterceptors returns [not null][20/4/21 18:56:40:925 IST] 00000001 TrustAssociat 3  TAI class name[0]: com.ibm.ws.security.web.saml.ACSTrustAssociationInterceptor[20/4/21 18:56:40:925 IST] 00000001 TrustAssociat < isTaiClassConfigured returns [false] Exit

Comment: Here isTaiClassConfigured is false ..Looks like SAML TAI class not getting configured.    TrustAssociat < isTaiClassConfigured returns [false] Exit